# not display font-awesome social media logo

Tags: html, css

need print social media logo using font-awesome
this is css call to my html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
```

html

```
<ul class="social-media list-inline">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pinterest"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-dribbble"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-behance"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

not display anything only square display here how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure your path is correct. Your code works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8sknuw4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following script and try again

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e2d16502eb.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your font-files path is wrong or you are using old library of font awesome. check below snippet it working fine with 4.7.0 version.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul class="social-media list-inline">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pinterest"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-dribbble"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-behance"></span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix try replacing the local folder with the fontawesome CDN.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`